# /dev/loop7 and /dev/loop6 created after installing uTorrent

Tags: partitioning, mount

I installed uTorrent and it seems it might have mounted some drives in my PC named /dev/loop6 and /dev/loop7.
When uninstalling uTorrent I accidentally left it running and so I think both drives did not get removed with it.

How do I get rid of them? Unmounting doesn't do anything.

EDIT: logging out did remove /dev/loop7, but did **not** remove /dev/loop8
RESOLVED: turning the PC off and of resolved the issue, as well as uninstalling wine

[list of all drives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6FkE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- uninstall wine
- uninstall utorrent
- turn the PC off and on back again
  RESOLVED